# Why shouldn't I use ransack to only simplify query generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, ransack

I found this statement right at the beginning of ransack README.

> If you're looking for something that simplifies query generation at the model or controller layer, you're probably not looking for Ransack.

I'm using rails as an API only, but I still would like to use ransack instead of handling the query generation by myself (scopes, extra code in the controller, etc), are there reasons not to use ransack only for that without using the view part of it?

If yes then what better suits my need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ransack is really a tool for converting key-value pairs, like `name_eq: 'ransack'` into an ActiveRecord clause like `where(name: 'ransack')`.

In the back end, you might as well write the ActiveRecord clause.

Having said that, if you are using Rails as an API only that doesn't mean there is no use for Ransack. We use it to process GraphQL query arguments that specify searches, and it's great for that.